# Regarding store and retrieve in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, reference, perl-data-structures

```
$stored_var = retrieve("$batch_text");
%some_hash= %$stored_var;
```

i think that this is for retrieving some stored hash. what does the %$ signify? Is it just the syntax  or does it have more involved meaning?

```
store \%batch_hash, "$batch_text";
```

I assume the above is used to store the hash. Here also I have the same doubt about \% as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what does the `%$` signify?

`$stored_var` is a hash reference  and `%$` is used to dereference it.

```
store \%batch_hash, "$batch_text";
```

`%batch_hash` is a hash and `\%` is used to pass the reference, so in store subroutine, you are passing reference of batch_hash hash as first parameter and `$batch_text` variable as second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`%$` is just the syntax for dereferencing a referenced hash. 
Take a look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). The `\%` is for referencing a hash. So `store` is a function which needs to called with a hashref (1. Param).

The `%some_hash= %$stored_var;` Part is to copy a hashref to a new hash. You need to dereference it and then it can be copied.

Answer (score 0):

`%$foo` is de-referencing a reference `$foo` to a hash, so a line

```
%bar = %$foo;
```

is (shallow) copying the contents of a hash referenced by a scalar variable into another hash, accessed more directly by a hash variable.

In some ways yes this is "just syntax" i.e. just a way of de-referencing. One important detail is that `store` and `retrieve` will not work directly to serialise hashes or arrays, so you have to use references to them (in scalar values).

The line would fail if `$foo` was not a reference to a hash.